# How to create column names from txt files in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a txt file which does not have column names.
When I try importing it using pandas.read_csv, the first row becomes the column names.

the txt file is such as:

```
0 9 8 2 1

1 2 3 2 2

2 3 4 5 3
```

How can I import this txt file successfully without the first row (0 9 8 2 1) being column names for the data frame?

And how can I insert the column names in the data frame?

Comment: Use `header=None` in read_csv, and pass `names=[...]` a list with your custom column headers.

Comment: Thank you very much @cs95 it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If no header:
   Load csv with no header using pandas read_csv
   If your csv file does not have header, then you need to set header = None while reading it .
2. To pass columns:
   pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.

> > > pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, usecols=(COL-ARRAY-IN-ORDER')